# How do I make my logs show up in yarn from my flink job?

Tags: java, log4j, apache-flink, slf4j, flink-streaming

I have a flink job that uses slf4j for logging but when I run the job, the logs do not show up in yarn. Do I need a log4j.properties or is there something else I have to configure?

I am just doing logger.info("info msg")

Comment: The log files can be accessed via the Job-/TaskManager pages of the WebUI. The used Resource Provider (e.g., YARN) may provide additional means of accessing them. On Yarn by default (I'm not sure) you can't see logs while container is running...